# Interpreting an ARIMA model in Time series

Tags: arima

I would like to request your assistance in interpreting this model in Time series.
$$
(1 − B) (1 − B_{4})(1 − 0.43B_4)X_t = (1 + 0.22B)(1 + 0.88B_4)W_t.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The seasonal ma polynomial (coeff =.88) is effectively cancelling the seasonal difference . I suggest that you simplify your model by eliminating the seasonal difference irrespective of the poor guidance by your software's overfitting  . Make sure that the model errors don't suggest pulses and/or level shifts or other gaussian requirements otherwise you have effectively mis-modelled.

Answer (score 0):

Time series models usually do not have *interpretation* the same way that cross section econometrics has.

What you can interpret (assuming you have a series with quarterly frequency) is that the model is a SARIMA.